# Move branch head to another commit

Tags: git

I know this is probably easy to do but I'm not managing to do it.

I want to move the  `develop` branch up in the tree to be in line with `master`.

When I try to ff merge `develop` into `master`, I get the notification that is already up to date.
See the image below for details.

[image: Branch History]

Comment: What sequence of commands are you using? It's hard to say what you're doing wrong when you aren't saying what you're doing. "When I try to ff merge `develop` into `master`..." Please tell us how you are ff merging `develop` into `master`. My guess is that you are not issuing the correct sequence of commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a fast forward merge with the following 2 steps:

```
git checkout develop
git merge master
```

Comment: This works, but I would like to understand why the other way doesn't. I Might be missing some basic logic behind the process.

Comment: As far as I can tell, merge does not take two arguments as described in the other answer; at least it does not seem to in my version of git. So when you type `git merge develop master`, git interprets it as `git merge develop`, and tries to merge develop into your current branch. At least, that is the behavior I see on my machine, and it seems you are seeing the same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Merge master into develop

```
$ git merge master
```

Comment: Doing this gives me: "Already up to date" as described in the OP.

Comment: maybe you did it while in master

Comment: Nop, even in upstream it gave the same message.

Comment: `git merge develop master` does not mean "Merge master into develop". It means "merge develop and master into my current branch." If your current branch is develop, then this is a nop.

Comment: `git merge master` does not merge master into develop. It merges master into your current branch. The OPs' problem is that the wrong branch is current. Your solution doesn't solve that.